# Рекурсивный поиск в json-строке

Tags: jquery, json

Допустим, есть json-файл с подобными строками:

```
[  
    {  
        "code":"XIY",
        "name":"Xianyang",
        "coordinates":{  
            "lon":108.75605,
            "lat":34.441154
        },
        "time_zone":"Asia/Shanghai",
        "name_translations":{  
            "de":"Xian Xianyang",
            "en":"Xianyang",
            "zh-CN":"西安咸阳机场",
            "tr":"Xi'an Xianyang Havalimanı",
            "ru":"Синьян",
            "it":"Xianyang",
            "fr":"Xianyang",
            "es":"Xianyang",
            "th":"ท่าอากาศยานนานาชาติซีอานเสียนหยาง"
        },
        "country_code":"CN",
        "city_code":"SIA"
    }
]
```

Допустим, что таких строк множество. В таком json-файле мне нужно выполнить поиск: я хочу найти все массивы, в которых значение **country_code** равняется **CN** и вытащить из подходящих условию поиска массивов значение поля **name**. Для такой задачи на серверной части своего приложения я использую рекурсивный поиск по массиву:

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false))
            return $current_key;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Но в этом случае поиск будет выполняться не один раз при загрузке страницы, а столько, сколько захочет пользователь и это критично для вычислительных ресурсов сервера. В связи с этим я решил переложить эту задачу на jQuery.

**Вопрос:** можно ли на jQuery выполнять рекурсивный поиск прямо из json-строки? Или на JS это работает как-то иначе?

Comment: jQuery как-бы для манипуляций с DOM придуман ващета

Comment: @Jean-Claude ващета сейчас у меня всё настроено уже так, что json-отлично выводится и сортируется при помощи JS. Проблема в том, что при загрузке страницы выводится очень много элементов и страница жутко тормозит. Мне нужно лишь сделать динамическую систему поиска и вывода затребованных значений, чтобы изначально страница была пуста, но при выборе фильтров из json-строка выбирались нужные значения.

Comment: так почему не перебрать массив на предмет поиска CN вроде такого http://jsbin.com/tiziquwini/edit?html,console ?

Comment: @Jean-Claude интересно, а у меня получится хранить в переменной 2.7мб json-строку? :D

Comment: на всяк случай: если к примеру выводится огромная таблица, то задание ширины фиксированной столбцов в разы повышает скорость отрисовки браузером.